# Django rest framework serializer - Serialize single model field multiple times

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I would like to serialize one related field multiple times in output json. The first should contain `pk` of related object, and the second representation should be hyperlink. Any fancy way how to do it? I know `SerializerMethodField`, but I find it non-elegant approach.

## My models:

```
 class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    ...

 class Order(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='orders')
```

## What I want:

Serialize my Order model like this:

```
{
    "title": "Alice in wonderland",
    "person": 1,  # represents persons's primary key
    "person_url": "/person-detail/1" 
}
```

## What I tried / My serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = serializers.IntegerField()
    person_url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='myapp:user-profile',
        lookup_field='pk'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['title', 'person', 'person_url']
        read_only_fields = ('__all__',)
```

But it this case Django was logically bitching about missing `person_url` field in database. How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is pretty close.  Couple of notes:

1. you don't need to specify the `person` integer field if you want the pk, you get that for free (`ModelSerializer` will automatically create a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` called `person`)
2. you don't have to specify the `fields` here.  DRF gives you the automatically generated ones plus explicitly defined fields on the serializer
3. `lookup_field` defaults to `pk`
4. assuming that your view name is correct (I can't see your urls), all you're missing from your `HyperlinkRelatedField` is a `source` attribute

Putting it together, something like this should work:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person_url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='myapp:user-profile',
        source='person',
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields='__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('__all__',)
```

NOTE: for my urls.py, I have a view name that looks more like `person-detail`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Looks like I overlooked a `person` param.

Comment: You were right, though: I was missing `Meta.fields`.  Not sure if the explicit `read_only` parameter is required when you have `read_only_fields`, but I added those in just in case.

Comment: Dont get fooled by my deleted comment. Read only stuff related failiure was caused by my local unrelated code.